# How to fetch UI Grid Component data from external REST API

Tags: magento2, magento-admin

We are trying to create a admin grid using UI Component and need to fetch data from external rest API, not able to figure-out the exact file from where we can inject this json data

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow this guide for creating a new UI component backend.
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/creat-a-ui-form-in-magento-2.html

Once the UI component is created, check here how you create your custom source data:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_data_source.html

Your custom suorce data should not be a standard collection, but it will have to call a class that executes the specific curl call you need. This data will then be injected through the dataProvider.

It is not easy to explain it is a complex process if developed according to magento specifications

Cheers

Comment: yes this seems to be the right approach have implemented something similar

Answer (score -1):

For this you had to install a module. Declare a public URL in the module.
access that URL and inside the "execute" function of controller, call external rest API with curl command.

app/code/vendorname/modulname/Controller/Fetchdata.php

```
<?php
namespace vendorname\modulname\Controller;

class Fetchdata extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //execute Curl call to external rest api here.
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          "cache-control: no-cache"
        ),
       ));

       $response = curl_exec($curl);
       $err = curl_error($curl);

       curl_close($curl);


        //than push response from curl call to insert data into grid table 
        //using mysql query


        $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
       $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();

       $themeTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('yourtablename');
       $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $themeTable . "(field1, field2) VALUES ('1', 'NameABC')";
       $connection->query($sql);
    }
}
```

for publick URL, you can use this file.

app/code/vendorname/modulename/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="fetch_rest_api_data" frontName="fetch_rest_api_data">
            <module name="vendorname_modulename" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now in browser, run this url http://yourmagentourl.com/fetch_rest_api_data/fetchdata
i-e http://yourmagentourl.com/RoutFrontName/ControllerName

Comment: How can we call this from admin grid?

Comment: you run this url once in chrome http://yourmagentourl.com/fetch_rest_api_data/fetchdata It will automatically fetch data from api to your grid table. Than you run grid in admin, you will check that grid is  populated from external rest api data.